# EclipseApplication Crash on button Click

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Have a very very simple program that crashes as soon as a button is clicked. Any help is appreciated thanks! App runs on emulator and crashes when button is pressed. I also tried making the same app using onClickListener yet that app crashed immediately upon start up. I have spent hours trying to figure out why noone of this is working. I cant seem to get apps that actually supply some function even though the Hello World app works fine, and this app displays a button that simply crashes the app.

```
package com.example.bryan;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void displayMessage(View v) {
    display.setText("Hello World!");
}
```

}

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bryan.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:onClick="displayMessage"
    android:text="Button" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check the logcat. There should be some stacktraces logged that help you debugging your app

Comment: Also the posted code seems to be incomplete, because I cannot see the Activity onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : 
Let the app implement OnClickListener so that you don't have to create new OnClickListeners

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
    ....etc


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int id= v.getId();

    if(id==R.id.yourId) 
    //do your action

    else if(id=....)
    //do something
    .
    .
    .   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have all this code in a class.  Moreover you should work in an activity, so you should always have a onCreate method.

Look at this link for more info :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

If you right click your project and choose new>Activity, you'll have a new activity that appears. I advise you to check its structure and compare it to the link I shared with you.